# Alter Procedure statement in Visual Studio gives 'This statement is not recognized in this context message'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012

Using Visual Studio 2012.  Open Sql Server Object Explorer, open a database.

Click on an existing stored procedure and then right click on "View Code"  This will open up a window with a Create Procedure.

Now, change 'create' to 'alter' in order to modify the procedure.  Visual Studio will give the error: SQL70001 :: This statement is not recognized in this context.

So how do I alter a procedure from Visual Studio?

*EDIT*

The solution to this issue is to copy all the text, close all windows, open a new script, paste it in and then it works fine.

Greg

Comment: You don't `MODIFY` a stored procedure in SQL Server, you `ALTER`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Alter.  It gives the same message with 'Alter"

Comment: Are you sure it opened in *a new window*? Did the procedure change names after you created it, and maybe it has its wires crossed and is somehow tied to the old name? I had no problem doing exactly what you describe in the question, so there must be some other variable you're not telling us about.

Comment: OK, thanks for checking this.  I don't know what the issue is, but I will try some more as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try closing Visual Studio and starting over. I bet it is re-using a window that has some ties to the wrong object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to modify the stored procedure, syntax is

```
 ALTER  procedure [dbo].
```

Comment: Even with 'Alter' it gives the same message.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and found the solution from this [website](https://arcanecode.com/2013/03/28/ssdt-error-sql70001-this-statement-is-not-recognized-in-this-context/).

The solution was to go into the property window of the stored procedure and change the Build Action setting to 'None'.

Comment: Then why do you need a project? Just write the SQL code in text file, if you don't want it to be compiled.

Comment: bad advice. Turning this to None defeats the purpose of SQL Projects.